# smtp sendmail in Dockerised Golang Web App in GAE doesn't work

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, go, smtp

I have a dockerised web app deployed on GAE wriiten in Go. The payment module uses stripe checkout API and on success triggers an email notification.

On debugging, I observe that the following line of code is not executed. I have tried port 587 and the result is the same.

```
 err := smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:465", auth, from, []string{to}, []byte(msg))
```

I have the same app on my local m/c and this feature works on it. Am not using docker on my local m/c though.

I am using the same user credentials as my GAE account in the 'from' user fields.  Could that be the reason that the code fails. Or should the smtp service auth parameters along with the port to be exposed be described in the dockerfile. What would be the correct way to map port 465 or 587 in GAE given that only 4 ports are available?
I am using Golang image 1.7.1

docker logs doesn't show any errors. But the email doesn't get sent.

etc/resolv.conf of the container has the following DNS entries

```
search c.cloud-devshell-prod.internal. google.internal.
nameserver 169.254.169.254
options: ndots5
```

Would appreciate any suggestions..

Thanks

Comment: What is the error? You are setting it to `err`, so, log it and tell us.

Comment: Ok. I created a simple file email.go and called the sendmail function in the App Engine and did not use docker. The mail doesn't get send and there are no errors.  I am using the App Engine Flexible Environment.

Comment: I had a similar problem when sending emails via SMTP on Dockerized golang applications using `FROM scratch` image (not on Google App Engine, though) and I solved it by specifying the volume: `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. Don't know if it applies also to GAE apps as well. Hope it can help @user3809560 :)

Answer (score 0):

Followed instructions on the link

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/sending-emails-with-mailgun

Set up and account with mailgun and got it to work. Mails get sent after running docker.